# reading docx (Office Open XML) in PHP

Tags: php, import, ms-word, office-2007

I want to add an word import function to our CMS, the only problem I cannot seems to find a good library for reading docx files (Word 2007).

Do anyone has some recommendations, the library should be able to extract content of the document and basic styling like italic, bold, superscript?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, since you requested a library, you may want to look into something like [Docvert](http://holloway.co.nz/docvert/index.html). I was just looking around based on your question, and it's my favorite so far for PHP. You input the word file location, it transforms it into something simple with the attributes and all that good stuff.

Comment: looks promising but I would have to make an API of it.

Answer (score 11):

`docx` files are actually just containers for the document's XML. You should be able to unzip the docx file and then go to the word folder inside, then to the document.xml. This has the actual text. But things like the fonts and styles are in other xml files in the docx container, so you'll probably want to mess around a bit and figure out what is what and how to match it up (start by using namespaces, I bet).

But yea, unzip the file, then use simplexml to convert it into something you can actually mess around with.

Comment: Thanks but I am wondering if someone didn't came with a library to do that. I would do some XSLT processing if I really need.

Comment: See my other answer. The only thing that I don't like about it is the lack of easy to find API

Comment: the class TbsZip can read (and even edit) the content of zip archives without any dependency nor any temporary files. XML analysis can be done with several other tools.

Answer (score 4):

There is a library to do this but it works with **Zend framework** may be it will help you
It is called **phpLiveDocx** : http://www.phplivedocx.org/downloads/
The library is licensed under New Bcd

Answer (score 4):

[PHPDocX PRO](http://www.phpdocx.com/) includes a TransformDoc class that can read .docx (zip) files and generate XHTML (or PDF) from it:

```
...
require_once 'phpdocx_pro/classes/TransformDoc.inc';
$doc = new TransformDoc();
$doc->setStrFile($file->filepath);
$doc->generateXHTML();
$html = $doc->getStrXHTML();
```

Answer (score 3):

I have just find a library that has both reading and writing support check it on the codeplex forge http://openxmlapi.codeplex.com and it is licensed under **GPLv2** .

Answer (score 0):

Convert a docx document to a odt using [OpenOffice](http://www.oooninja.com/2008/01/convert-openxml-docx-etc-in-linux-using.html). Use then [eZ Components](http://ezcomponents.org/docs/tutorials/Document#open-document-text) to do the parsing and import. They actually use the import in their CMZ [eZ Publish](http://ez.no/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working solution I found

http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_the_clean_text_from_docx_odt.php