# How php work with docx file

Tags: php

How php work with docx file.
hi, I wont to open docx file replace some variable.

in *.docx file have 
Name : {variable1}
Address : {variable2}

use php 5.1 version

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501623/reading-docx-office-open-xml-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout some PHP libraries below:
PHPDocX: http://www.phpdocx.com/
OpenTBS: http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php

Comment: Thank you for response.

second link not for free.

firs link i try but have problem. (can not understand)
in demo_ms_word.php file

$yourname = "(no name)";

replace text. but how orginaize Name : {variable1} Address : {variable2}

Answer (score 0):

`.docx` files are just `zip` files containing other files. You can try to unzip one using your favourite uzipping tool and explore it to locate the things you need to replace. Then you can proceed with PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple library to do so: [Github](https://github.com/igorrebega/docx-replacer)

Code example:

Text to text replace
This code will replace **$search** to **$replace** in **$pathToDocx** file

```
$docx = new IRebega\DocxReplacer($pathToDocx);

$docx->replaceText($search, $replace);
```