# How to extract text from docx file?

Tags: php, docx

Can anybody help me to extract text from docx file in php?
Or is there any linux command for this?

I can extract text from pdf and doc, so docx to pdf or doc conversion in php (or linux command) will also work for me.

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501623/reading-docx-office-open-xml-in-php

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to extract the text from the docx, you don't even need a dependency (except for the zip module which you should activate)

```
<?php

function read_docx($filename) {
    $striped_content = '';
    $content = '';

    $zip = zip_open($filename);

    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip))
        return false;

    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE)
            continue;

        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml")
            continue;

        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }// end while

    zip_close($zip);

    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
    $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

    return $striped_content;
}


echo read_docx("textExample.docx");
```

Thanks to [Muhammad's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362149/trying-to-read-content-of-docx-file-but-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`OpenTBS`](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/plugins/opentbs/tbs_plugin_opentbs.html).

After including it ..  Do like this..

```
include_once('tbs_class.php');
include_once('../tbs_plugin_opentbs.php');
$TBS = new clsTinyButStrong;
$TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN);
$TBS->LoadTemplate('filename.docx');
echo $string = $TBS->Source; // your docx content is now in this variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the text from docx file, please find the below code and you need to install ZipArchive file

```
public function docx_to_text($filename)
{
    $input_file = 'tmp_file.zip';
    copy($filename, $input_file);    //copy file with path (content) to temp.zip file

    $xml_filename = "word/document.xml"; //content file name
    $zip_handle = new ZipArchive;
    $output_text = "";

    if(true === $zip_handle->open($input_file))
    {
        if(($xml_index = $zip_handle->locateName($xml_filename)) !== false)
        {
            $xml_datas = $zip_handle->getFromIndex($xml_index);
            $xml_handle = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml_datas, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            $output_text = strip_tags($xml_handle->saveXML());
        }
        else
        {
            $output_text .="";
        }
        $zip_handle->close();
    }
    else
    {
        $output_text .="";
    }
    return $output_text;
}
```