# Function to get the content of a docx in php

Tags: php, zip, docx

```
 private function read_docx($filename) {
    var_dump($filename);
    $striped_content = '';
    $content = '';

    $zip = zip_open($filename);

    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip))
        return false;

    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE)
            continue;

        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml")
            continue;

        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }// end while

    zip_close($zip);

    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
    $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

    return $striped_content;
}
```

I have used the above code for displaying `.docx` content in my `view` using the below code:

```
  <div style="padding: 10px">
    <?php
    $fileName = $details->resume_name;
    $path = FCPATH . "uploads/document/";
    // i have also tried.. $path = base_url() . "uploads/document/"; and $path = FCPATH . "uploads/document/";
    $fullPath = $path . $fileName;                     
    echo $CI->docx->read_docx($fullPath);                      
    ?>
   </div>
```

But when I run this code it shows me nothing and the result is empty....

Please help me to solve this problem.. or suggest me any similar way to read the content of `.docx` file and display it in a simple `html page` or in a `view`

Comment: And where did you set `$CI` variable?

Comment: `$CI =& get_instance()`

Comment: i have used `var_dump` at first line of the `read_docx` method and it is displaying me right path..but result coming is empty..

Comment: Did you load the `docx` library at first? (within Controller?)

Comment: ya sir... and it is showing me the `var_dump` value which i have written at the first line of the `read_docx` method..

Comment: The code you have written works for me: http://pastebin.com/ZvGiMv4N with this document: http://javascript-ninja.fr/docxgenjs/examples/textExample.docx

Comment: can u suggest me what may be the posible reason.. why this is not working on my localhost server.. and i have not tried this on live server..

Comment: Try to add var_dumps inside the while to get every files name and content, I think that could be the issue.

Comment: i have tried as you sueggested but it is not showing me anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its working now.. i am answering my own question so that any one else can get help from it...

the problem is with the path here `$path = FCPATH . "uploads/document/";`

which I have replaced with `$path = "./uploads/document/";`